# how to submit a form with file uploading using ajax...?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file

i created a form. Thats shown below...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#sbt").click(function(){
    var re=$("#file").val();



$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "loadajax.php",
            data: $("#data").serialize()+ '&photo=' +re,
            success: function(data) {

                $("#datas").html(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                  alert('error handing here');
            }
        });

});
});

</script>
```

**Ajax response page**

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);

var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

All input values are returned.but file is not uploaded.I don't know how to upload file using ajax. Please help me...

Comment: Use some Jquery Plugin such as "jquery Form" malsup.com/jquery/form/   supports all kinds of browsers too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
$("#sbt").click(function(){
var pht = $("#ph").val();
var str2 = "your_folder/"; // destination folder, if needed
var upvid = str2.concat(pht);   

var data = new FormData();
data.append( 'photo', $('#photo')[0].files[0] );
data.append( 'pht', pht );



$.ajax({
        type: "POST",               
        url: "loadajax.php",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache:true,
        data: data,             
        success: function(data){
           $("#datas").html(data
        } ,
        error: function(){
              alert('error handing here');
        }
    });     
});



<?php
$a = $_POST['pht'];
$file = str_replace( "\\", '/', $a );
$ofile = basename($file);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun BS.This is working, but form input values are not getting. How to implement form.serialze() in this code...???

Comment: You must put <form action="yourpage.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">. And i know serializeArray().

var some_var= { };
$.each($('#form_id').serializeArray(), function() {
    some_varthis.name] = this.value;
});

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a plugin for this, jQuery doesn't support this out of the box. The best know plugin is [ajaxForm](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

This will post the form to the given url in the form action field using ajax. There are events available to add validations and post-submit funcions.

Comment: You don't need another plugin to upload files with AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

you can also do like this:

```
function upload() {
    // id of the form "documentUploadForm"
    var form = document.getElementById("documentUploadForm");
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = '<c:url value="/loadajax.php"/>';
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            outputData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log("Response:" +outputData);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```